# semver caret behavior differ between npm install and update

Tags: npm, semantic-versioning

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "pr",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

When I run `npm install`, I get version 2.0.8

```
⇒  npm install
pr@1.0.0 /Users/shlomitc/WebstormProjects/pr
└── typescript@2.0.8
```

When I run `npm update` I get version 2.1.1!

```
⇒  npm update
pr@1.0.0 /Users/shlomitc/WebstormProjects/pr
└── typescript@2.1.1
```

Why npm install and update behaves differently?

Comment: If this is consistently reproducible (delete `node_modules` and try again), you might want to report this to the npm issue tracker.

Comment: It is reproducible. tried it on node 4.2.1, 6.2.1, 6.9.1

Answer (score 0):

According to npm guys, this is the correct behavior, it's just not described well enough in the docs.

`npm install` installs the `latest` tagged version, currently `2.0.8`

`npm update` installs the highest possible version, currently `2.1.1`

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/14586